# Why does ItemCount go down, but nothing was evicted?

Tags: caching, appfabric

I have perfmon running w/ the counters indicated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921021%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), it never shows anything getting evicted, but when I run Get-CacheStatistics in powershell, the ItemCount is constantly increasing and decreasing.  Can anyone shed any light on this seemingly odd behavior?

Oh yeah, I also have my cache configured as 
TimeToLive           : 10 mins
CacheType            : Partitioned
Secondaries          : 0
IsExpirable          : False
EvictionType         : LRU
NotificationsEnabled : True

Basically I don't want anything to be evicted, but if it has to use LRU.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, although I don't understand why it happens.  It seems that the TTL is not ignored even if IsExpirable is false.  It turns out that items were expiring not being evicted.